# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I'm using Flask server in a Raspberry Pi with archlinux arm.

I have one script called rest.py wich contains the necessary to connect with the BDD:

```
 (...)
 DATABASE   = 'stuff.db'
 (...)
 top.sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
 (etc)
```

**If I execute the file.py the servers runs propertly**, it establish the connection and then you can do the RESTs calls perfectly, you can GET, POST, etc.

But, when I execute the file.py using an script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 sudo python file.py
```

..doesn't work. I get the following error: **sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user**

I've tried to grant absolute permissions to all files (chmod 777..., I know its not a good practice but I don't know what to do... ). So directory /tmp and the parent directory of the file.py and stuff.db are with full permissions.

I've also tried to eliminate the DBB and re-create it. Still the same.

Any idea guys?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This code appears to open the file `stuff.db` in some random directory.

Comment: Exactly @CL. !!! Thank you so much... I solve the problem adding the absolute path to the DBB .... cheers

Answer (score 1):

I meet a similar problem:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("UPDATE COMPANY set SALARY = 25000.00 where ID=1")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Then I add a line of code after "c = conn.cursor()":

```
conn.commit()
```

The problem is solved.